# Why are my two SQL iterations different?

Tags: sqlalchemy, iteration

I have the following SQLAlchemy iteration in python:

```
for business in session.query(Business).filter(Business.name.like("%" + term + "%")):
    print business.name
```

I have about 7000 businesses in my list, and this runs in under 10ms. Great!
However, I want to support a more specific search algorithm than like - for example, I want to match & with and, and so forth. So, I tried the following:

```
for business in session.query(Business):
    if term in business.name:
        print business.name
```

The latter takes about 600ms to run. What is SQLAlchemy doing in its filter call that makes the iteration so much faster? How can I make mine faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SA does nothing to optimize your query.
The difference you have is between:

1. *filter data on RDBMS directly* on one hand and
2. *load **all** rows from the database into memory, then filter out those not needed.*

Obviously, the second version is going to be much slower, especially if the number of rows is large. In fact, the SA might even contribute to your second version being slower, as it creates `Business` objects for every row in the database, which depending on your model might be relatively expensive operation. Furthermore, if you have eager-load relationships, it will load those too. Just run two queries below against database directly to see how many rows each returns:

```
SELECT * FROM Business WHERE Name LIKE '%term%';
SELECT * FROM Business;
```

I would suggest using SQL engine filtering capabilities for large number of objects, as you can do most of the filtering directly there much more efficiently

Comment: thank you! could you suggest such a filtering capability? I'm working with SQLite but MySQL is also an option

Comment: @Raiders. I do not mean any special filtering capabilities but a `WHERE` statement. The real difference is that in this case you only load some data rows from the database and create Python objects for them, whereas in the current setup you load **ALL** rows from the table, crate Python objects for them, and then discard some; apart from taking more time those objects still all stay in the memory.